# Is there a better SQL query to find ranking of a single row in database?

Tags: postgresql, rank

I would like to obtain the ranking of a user's points in their country. For example, 23rd highest points in the US.

After some Googling, I found that the `RANK` function would be the best solution. Here is my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT points_ranking FROM 

    (
        SELECT
            user_country,
            user_id,
            user_points,
            RANK () OVER ( 
                ORDER BY user_points DESC
            ) points_ranking
        
        FROM data.user
        WHERE
            user_country iLIKE 'usa'
    ) as subquery
    
WHERE
    user_id = 3
```

However, I'm unsure if this is highly inefficient or if there's a better way. I ask this because I'm concerned the inner query would be ranking every single row in the table, just to select one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm concerned the inner query would be ranking every single row in the table, just to select one.

How would one know which row is ranked #23 without ranking all the other rows relative to it though? Think about a randomly sorted deck of cards with some of the cards missing. It would be impossible to rank them in ascending order of their face values, and select a specific card by rank, without sorting all of them first.

It does need to analyze the other rows, but if they're already pre-sorted by your `ORDER BY` criteria, then it's a much more efficient analyzation. You can pre-sort the rows by creating an index that covers your `ORDER BY` clause. For example the index `CREATE INDEX IX_data_user_rank ON data.user (user_points desc) INCLUDE (user_country, user_id, user_points)` covers your `RANK()` window function's `ORDER BY` clause (and the other fields being `SELECT`ed). It'll persist the data, ordered by the `user_points` column descending.

By persisting the data already sorted appropriately, that'll eliminate the need to scan the entire table and sort it, in order to run your `RANK()` window function. This will improve the efficiency of your query.